# clone element using next in js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a section in which contains two div, one div is created dynamically, now I would like to copy the other div which is not created dynamically into the div which is created dynamically

```js
let adContainer = $('#adContainer').html();
adContainer.next().html(adContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="adContainer">
</div>

<div style="width:100%; height:100%">
   <video></video>
</div>
```

This is not working, what is wrong here?

Comment: Yep, that was just typing error, but problem still there

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `clone()` and `appendTo()` methods of jQuery:

```
$('#adContainer').clone().appendTo($('#adContainer').next());
```

read more here: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Also next() should be called directly on the element, not the html() of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Your code don't work because you try to use `next()` with `html`  and not with `div`. so you must select div and html in two variable like:

```js
let div =$('#adContainer');
let adContainer = div.html();
div.next().html(adContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="adContainer">
<p>hello</p>
</div>

<div style="width:100%; height:100%">
   <video></video>
</div>
```

Comment: Dead Man have you test it?